# Recursive function inside for loop not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I was trying to print first array element using recursive function but output is not as expected.

```
var modelArray = [1,2,3];
var refurbArray = [a,b];
for (var z = 0; z < modelArray.length; z++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < refurbArray.length; y++) {
        var check = modelArray[z];
        var recursive(refurbArray[y], function() {
            consol.log(check);
        });
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

Obtained output:

```
3
3
3
3
3
3
```

Comment: where is`recursive` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `recursive` have deferred the call to your call back function (likely due to some async functionality inside the `recursive`), and the value of `check` has changed when the callback function is finally executed.

You need to bind the `check` in a closure, for which there are several options and coding style on how to do, but example like

```
for (var z = 0; z < modelArray.length; z++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < refurbArray.length; y++) {
        (function() {
           var check = modelArray[z];
           recursive(refurbArray[y], function() {
               consol.log(check);
           });
        })();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like:

```
var modelArray = [1,2,3];
var refurbArray = ['a','b'];
function recursive(val, cb){
   cb();
}
for (var z = 0; z < modelArray.length; z++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < refurbArray.length; y++) {
        var check = modelArray[z];
        recursive(refurbArray[y], function() {
            console.log(check);
        });
    }
}
```

You print the `check` variable in the `refurbCallback` and that remains set to the last value of `var check = modelArray[z];`

Comment: I'm sure that the OP had something more elaborate in mind for the functionality of `recursive`